# Stop canvas from leaving frame tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to create pong and i have basic movement of the paddle, but how would you go about keeping the paddle on the screen? I have tried to read the cords and only allowing moment if cords is less then a certain amount, but the cords stay the same no matter the actual position of the paddle. Thoughts?edit: fixed it using DMcC answer

```
import tkinter as tk

ypong = 0


def keyup(e):
    global pongMovement
    global pongEdit
    global Pong
    pongMovement = pongMovement - 10
    pongEdit.place(x=1, y=pongMovement)
    pongEdit.update()
    print('YAY')


def keydown(e):
    global pongMovement
    global pongEdit
    global Pong
    pongMovement = pongMovement + 10
    pongEdit.place(x=1, y=pongMovement)
    pongEdit.update()
    print('YAY')


pongMovement = 0

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('600x600')
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
window.bind('<Up>', keyup)
window.bind('<Down>', keydown)
pongEdit = tk.Canvas(window, width=10, height=100, bg="black")
Pong = pongEdit.create_rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20, fill="red")
pongEdit.pack()

pongEdit.place(x=1, y=pongMovement)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding conditionals that check pongMovement seems to do it:

```
import tkinter as tk

ypong = 0


def keyup(e):
    global pongMovement
    global pongEdit
    global Pong
    if pongMovement > 0:
        pongMovement = pongMovement - 10
        pongEdit.place(x=1, y=pongMovement)
        pongEdit.update()
        print('YAY')


def keydown(e):
    global pongMovement
    global pongEdit
    global Pong
    if pongMovement < 500:
        pongMovement = pongMovement + 10
        print(pongMovement)
        pongEdit.place(x=1, y=pongMovement)
        pongEdit.update()
        print('YAY')


pongMovement = 0

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('600x600')
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
window.bind('<Up>', keyup)
window.bind('<Down>', keydown)
pongEdit = tk.Canvas(window, width=10, height=100, bg="black")
Pong = pongEdit.create_rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20, fill="red")
pongEdit.pack()

pongEdit.place(x=1, y=pongMovement)

window.mainloop()
```